# EF Code First How to specify DateTime as timestampz

Tags: npgsql

With Code First database creation, how a can one specify a DateTime property to take the postgres timestampz datatype instead of the default timestamp?. 
I am storing all dates as UTC, however have an issue with linq queries where the DateTime.Kind is Unspecified. I believe the timestampz should resolve this.

The below code examples attempt to use the 'Column' attribute, this results in an error (DateTime not compatible).

I am using npgsql v3.1.7 and EntityFramework6.Npgsql v 3.1.1

```
[Column(TypeName="timestampz")] 
public DateTime CreatedByDate { get; set; }

[Column(TypeName="NpgsqlDateTime")] 
public DateTime CreatedByDate { get; set; }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `TimeStamp` attribute in the namespace `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` to have .NET create a non-nullable Timestamp column in the database table that your entity represents.

```
[Timestamp]
public Byte[] TimeStamp { get; set; }
```

Code first allows only one Timestamp property per entity.